# Converse, Inverse, and Contrapositive: Please check my answers.

Tags: logic

Statement: If you finish your work, you can watch movies

converse -> If you can watch movies, then you finished your work.
inverse -> If you did not finish your work, then you can not watch movies.
contrapositive -> If you can not watch movies, then you did not finish your work.

Are they right?

Comment: I'm curious, why were you unsure of these in the first place?

Comment: From the amount of logic questions the OP has been asking, I think he is just preparing for an upcoming test.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Recall,

Statement: if $p$ then $q.$

Converse: if $q$ then $p.$

Inverse: if not $p$ then not $q.$

Contrapositive: if not $q$ then not $p.$

So, yes, your answers are indeed correct.